# Como funciona la memoria reservada para un string en C

Tags: c, manejo-de-memoria

tenia una duda con respecto a las cadenas en C, en este las cadenas son un array de chars pero la manera de trabajar con ellas es guardando solo la dirección de memoria del primer carácter, así avanzando en la dirección de memoria, se considera que el string termino cuando se encuentra un carácter nulo. Hasta ahora esto es lo que entiendo de las cadenas pero mi duda es:

Si la única referencia que tengo del string es su primer carácter al hacer

`free(myString)`

(siendo este un `char*` que contiene una cadena) ¿Solo liberaria la memoria del primer carácter? ¿debería hacer free a todos las caracteres de la cadena?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si tenias una duda, entonces ya no la tienes, no?

Bueno, las cadenas en C <s>no son mas que punteros a caracter *(`char *`)* como bien mencionas</s> son un tipo particular de vectores, que como su nombre lo dice son vectores de char, con la particularidad que tienen una marca en el fin del (el caracter '\0') *([Wikibooks](https://es.wikibooks.org/wiki/Programaci%C3%B3n_en_C/Cadenas_de_caracteres))*.

Empecemos por lo básico:

Un puntero es una direccion de memoria que apunta hacia otra dirección que contiene un valor, dicho esto, tenemos lo siguiente:

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+----+
| N | H | O | L | A |   | M | U | N | D | O | \n | <- Contenido de la memoria
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+----+
| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | A |  B | <- Posición de memoria
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+----+ 

[0] es NULL.
```

Asi es como funciona la memoria en C, luego de esto, lo que mencionas:

> ¿Solo liberaría la memoria del primer carácter?

La respuesta es simplemente **NO**, consideremos el siguiente ejemplo:

```
char *test = malloc(11); // Se piden 11 bytes de forma dinámica.
// Haz lo que sea con el "string"
free(test); // Se libera toda la memoria.
```

En la llamada a `free(void *);` se elimina todo el bloque de memoria pedido utilizando `malloc(size_t);`, debido a que la librería estándar de C conoce como administra la memoria, pero te deja la opción a ti de cuanta memoria necesitas, el solo la pide al sistema operativo.

Las llamadas a `free` solo liberan memoria reservada de forma dinámica, por lo que si haces lo siguiente:

```
char *test2 = "Hola Mundo\n";
free(test2); // ERROR!
```

Y respecto a tu segunda pregunta:

> ¿debería hacer free a todos las caracteres de la cadena?

De nuevo, **NO**! Ya con solo darle la primera dirección de memoria a `free(void *)` la función conoce todos y cada uno de los elementos que componen el puntero, es decir, su tamaño.

Normalmente si pides a `malloc` colocar 10 bytes para tu uso, `malloc` puede colocar 11 o 12 segun quiera, para conocer algo llamado *"pointer tag"*, que es lo que conoce toda la información del puntero que retorna la función, pero la mayoría de las plataformas son lo suficientemente *"inteligentes"* como para darte el puntero hacia memoria virtual, la cual no se pierde tan facil.

Comment: stackoverRAE Gracias por la info !